# HTML — Two Tables Horizontally Side by Side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display tables next to each other horizontally, but this is what I'm getting.
[image]

```
<tr>
<th>
      <span onclick="toggleDiv('favData', 'favDataImg')" style="cursor: hand;">Favorites <img   name="favDataImg" src="../images/minus.gif" /></span>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 300px; text-align: left; padding-right: 30px;">
<div id="favData" style="display: block;">
<fieldset style="width: 240px;">
<legend>Favorites</legend>
<table border="0" align="left">

<input type="radio" name="publicRadio" value="Public" >Public: </input>

<select  name="publicDropDown">
<option value="Public Dropdown" selected="selected">Public Dropdown</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="userRadio" value="User" >User: </input>

<select  name="userDropDown">
<option value="User Dropdown" selected="selected">User Dropdown</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="customRadio" value="Custom" >Custom: </input>

</table>
</fieldset>


<fieldset style="width: 240px;">
<legend>Favorites</legend>
<table border="0" align="left">

<input type="radio" name="publicRadio" value="Public" >Public: </input>

<select  name="publicDropDown">
<option value="Public Dropdown" selected="selected">Public Dropdown</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="userRadio" value="User" >User: </input>

<select  name="userDropDown">
<option value="User Dropdown" selected="selected">User Dropdown</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="customRadio" value="Custom" >Custom: </input>

</table>
</fieldset>



</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is this your full code? If yes, you have to add `<table>...</table>` around the block (it doesn't fix the problem, but your code will look better).

Comment: If you used Yahoo... try with Google ;) Joke. Set your floats (float:) properly and use with it a positioning method `position:relative;`.

Comment: well...this code is a include on another web page....thanks though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're missing a few lines of HTML from the start of your copy and paste, however what you'll want to do is add a `float:left` to the CSS of the first fieldset.

Answer (score 22):

This answer is taken from Chris Baker's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690480/610573) of a duplicate question.  Please up vote his answer.

One can use `float: left` or `display: inline-block` depending on content and space:

```
<table style="display: inline-block">

<table style="float: left">
```

This page is already setup with the HTML to try out and see how it looks in the browser: http://jsfiddle.net/SM769/

**Documentation**

- CSS `display` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS:display
- CSS `float` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float

**Example**

```
<table style="float: left">
   <tr>
      <td>..</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<table style="float: left">
   <tr>
      <td>..</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if I want a bit of space in between the two tables - either horizontal or vertical space depending on whether the second table wraps? Padding doesn't work, because some email clients ignore padding.

Comment: @user1279887 You could add a third table between the above two tables.  In the `<td>`, you could put `&nbsp;`.  Make sure you add `border=0` to the table to make it invisible.

Answer (score 6):

try to add to your CSS file:

```css
.table-wrapper {
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

I have tried with `display: inline-table`, with `float: left`, and other stuff, but not a single one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
fieldset
{
    float: left;
}
```

to your CSS. I copied your HTML to http://jsfiddle.net/S3n6D/ and added that CSS. You can see the result there.

Comment: tried adding <fieldset style="width: 240px; display: block; float: left;">     still on top each other

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply a CSS rule to your tables in order to follow the normal document float which is:

`table{ float:left; }`

or

`<table style="float: left;">.........</table>`

PS: Just make sure that this tag selector block won't affect any other tables that you don't them to be so, otherwise you are recommended to use ID or class selectors.

Comment: tried adding <fieldset style="width: 240px; display: block; float: left;">     still on top each other

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: table-cell;` to the tables may help.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html
And you may need to add wrapping div with `display: table;` or add that property to some element depending on your page structure.

Comment: did'nt seem to help...this is frustrating

Comment: try `display:inline-block;`. often just works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="float: left; border-collapse:collapse; " border=\"1px;\" >
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table style="border-collapse:collapse; " border=\"1px;\">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eveeve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Johnjohj</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To show two tables side by side, you can add the below CSS:

```
table.table1, table.table2{
    width:49.8%;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>tables sideXside2</title>
<style>

table, td  { border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 15px; color: #000000; text-align: center; }

table.pos_fixed1 { position:fixed; top:30px; left:10px; }

table.pos_fixed2 { position:fixed; top:30px; left:250px; }

table.pos_fixed3 { position:fixed; top:30px; left:490px; }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<table summary="" width="10%" class="pos_fixed1">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>

<table summary="" width="10%" class="pos_fixed2">
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
<tr><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td></tr>
</table>

<table summary="" width="10%" class="pos_fixed3">
<tr><td>i</td><td>ii</td><td>iii</td></tr>
<tr><td>iv</td><td>v</td><td>vi</td></tr>
<tr><td>vii</td><td>viii</td><td>ix</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way of doing it using `display: inline-block`

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="table1">
      <tr>
        <td>cell1</td>
        <td>cell2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table2">
      <tr>
        <td>cell1</td>
        <td>cell2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table#table1 {
  width: 40%;
  background: blue;
}

table#table2 {
  width: 60%;
  background: red;
}
```

For the full explanation, check https://uxengineer.com/inline-block-elements-100-percent-width/