# HTML -- two tables side by side

Tags: html, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to get tables next to each other horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917235/trying-to-get-tables-next-to-each-other-horizontal)

I have two html tables already created. How can I place them side by side instead of 1 above the other?

Comment: You can style them with CSS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets

Comment: Hi Matt, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a sample of your existing code? That will help us figure out what you are after, and make it easier to answer your question. Also, be sure to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Depending on your content and space, you can use floats or inline display:

```
<table style="display: inline-block;">

<table style="float: left;">
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/SM769/

**Documentation**

- CSS `display` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS:display
- CSS `float` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float

Comment: I don't think setting the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to inline-block should be the accepted answer, since a ´<table>´ element should explicitly have the ´display´ attribute set to ´table´. Otherwise, it does not behave exactly like a table.

Answer (score 16):

You can place your tables in a div and add style to your table "float: left"

```
<div>
  <table style="float: left">
    <tr>
      <td>..</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left">
    <tr>
      <td>..</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

or simply use css:

```
div>table {
  float: left
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned on themhz's answer, the wrapping divs are not necessary. Generally, one tries to achieve the desired presentation using as few tags as possible.

Comment: yes without div also float left works

Comment: Doesn't this cause an overfloat outside the div for large tables?

Answer (score 7):

```
<div style="float: left;margin-right:10px">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>..</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="float: left">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>..</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The wrapping divs aren't required -- you can float the tables themselves. Adding the divs just adds more markup, needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS: `table {float:left;}​` ?