# html table side by side: <table style="float: left;"> does not work

Tags: html, html-table

My goal is to put two tables side by side. I've followed following guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690480/2402577

> ```
> <table style="float: left;">
> ```

My example code:

```
<div class="container" id="coverpage">
  <div class="row">
     <table id="tableblock" class="display" width="100%" style="float:left"><caption><h3>Latest Blocks</h3></table>
     <table id="tabletxs"   class="display" width="100%" style="float:left"><caption><h3>Latest Transactions</h3></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Table's output:
[image]

As you can see the tables not places side by side. I am not sure what I did wrong. How could I fix this issue?

With valuable advices it seems working but now table's height is pretty small. Done changes: `<div class="col-md-10">` added, `width` removed: This works but now tables height is not symmetric and long enough.

```
<div class="container" id="coverpage">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">     
     <table id="tableblock" class="display"><caption><h3 style="color:black;">Latest Blocks</h3></caption></table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <table id="tabletxs"   class="display"><caption><h3 style="color:black;">Latest Transactions</h3></caption></table>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Since you are using `class` attributes, please edit your question and add your CSS code.

Comment: I see you are using `container` and `row`. Does that mean you are using Bootstrap? Because that would make everything much easier.

Comment: Sidenote: `h3` is not allowed inside `caption`.

Comment: Yes  I am using Bootstrap @HubertGrzeskowiak

Comment: Both tables are 100% width, so they will wrap?   Can you not just set different widths?

Comment: When using Bootstrap, just use the correct `col-md-6` or whatever. And get rid of the `width="100%"

Comment: I have updated width as %40 but it did not make any change. @83N

Comment: Please post your css... You might have a property somewhere that is setting the width of `#tableblock` `#tabletxs` or `.display` to 100% or the display property to block

Comment: I have tried your guide but it did not work as well, you could see me updated code. @HubertGrzeskowiak

Comment: See my answer on how to apply Bootstrap classes properly.

Comment: @Avatar your updated code still contains `float:left`. Get rid of that and the tables should work as expected.

Comment: Removing float:left did not fix the problem of the tables' height issue :( @HubertGrzeskowiak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it the Bootstrap way. It will show the tables side by side on middle to big screens and below each other on small screens.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" id="coverpage">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <table id="tableblock" class="table">
         <caption>Latest Blocks</caption>
         <tr><td>cell</td></tr>
       </table>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <table id="tabletxs" class="table">
         <caption>Latest Transactions</caption>
         <tr><td>cell</td></tr>
       </table>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you run the script here, it will run in a small window. You can click on the `Full page` link to the right to see it in a bigger window. This is intended and usually called Responsive Design @Avatar

Answer (score 2):

You have given table width as **100%**; so it will take its full width though you have given `float:left`

I have reduced your table width by **50%**.

```html
<div class="container" id="coverpage">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <table id="tableblock" class="display" width="50%" style="float:left"><caption><h3>Latest Blocks</h3></caption>
  </table>
  </div>
  
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <table id="tabletxs"   class="display" width="50%" style="float:left"><caption><h3>Latest Transactions</h3></caption>
     </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works! But tables' height it not long enough and not symmetric. Is it possible to make them longer. Please see my updated question. @Bhavin Shah

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>abc</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" id="coverpage">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <table id="tableblock" class="table">
         <caption>Latest Blocks</caption>
        <tr><td>cell</td></tr>
         <tr><td>cell</td></tr>
         <tr><td>cell</td></tr>
       </table>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <table id="tabletxs" class="table">
         <caption>Latest Transactions</caption>
         <tr><td>cell</td></tr>
         <tr><td>cell</td></tr>
         <tr><td>cell</td></tr>
       </table>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try `width: 50%;` in style, I think you can achieve what you want. Here is an hardcoded example of `width: 50%;`.

If you are using bootstrap then there are classes available to position things in GRID style. [Here you can read about it.](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<h1 style="float: left; width: 50%;">Table1</h1>
<h1 style="float: right; width: 50%;">Table2</h1>
<table id="table1" style="float: left; width: 50%;border: solid black 1px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>




<table id="table2" style="float: left; width: 50%; border: solid blue 1px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```