# HTML: How to increase tables' overall height if they are side-by-side?

Tags: html, html-table

I have followed following guide (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45672648/2402577) to put tables side-by-side. As output tables' heights are not symmetric and I am not able to make change both tables' height (I prefer to increase tables' displayed row number hence having a longer table).

My source code, please note that I am using Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container" id="coverpage">                                                                                                                       
  <div class="row">                                                                                                                                          
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">                                                                                                          
     <table id="tableblock" class="display"><caption><h3 style="color:black;">Latest Blocks</h3></caption></table>          
  </div>                                                                                                                                                     
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">                                                                                                        
     <table id="tabletxs"   class="display" ><caption><h3 style="color:black;">Latest Transactions</h3></caption></table>    
  </div>                                                                                                                                                     
  </div>                                                                                                                                                     
</div>
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see first table's displayed row number is 2. In original it should be 5  (when I comment out `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">`  ).

**[Q]** How could I make both tables' overall height larger (increase the the row number to be displayed) and make both tables symmetric?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize my mistake. When I increase `scrollY`: value it solved my problem, which is defined under `$(document).ready(function())`.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("btabl", function(result){
        $('#tableblock').DataTable( {
        data: result,
        scrollY: 800, //I increased this value.
        paging: false,
        info:   false,
        searching:   false,
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [0,1],
                render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                    if(type === 'display'){
                        data = " " + data ;
                        data = data.replace(/(@@(.+)@@)/,'<a onClick="a_onClick(' + "'" + "$2" + "'" + ')">' + "$2" + '</a>') ;
                        // data = '<a onClick="a_onClick(' + "'" + encodeURIComponent(data) + "'" + ')">' + data + '</a>';
                        // data = '<a href="search/' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
                    }

                    return data;
                }
            },
            {className: "dt-center", "targets": [0,1,2,3]}
        ],
        columns: [
            { title: "Block" },
            { title: "Mined By" },
            { title: "Time" },
            { title: "Txs" }
         ]
        })
    })
} ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could set min-height property using jquery if you are building the LatestBlocks table grid from db.

or you could use .css class for that and set min-height property for your second table if you think the height of first table is fixed

Answer (score -3):

You can use height and width attribute in CSS
For eg. in table tag:    height="100px"

Simmilarly, for the second table

Comment: It did not help.