# Split table in php

Tags: php

i got this script. it looks into a file and read all the lines and put it nicely in a table.. what i need to do now is to take all the table data and split it into two tables ..

eg. if their is 100 rows.. then instead of one long list, i will get 50 data in one table and the other 50 in the other table...

```
  enter code here<?php
    if(isset ($_GET['type'])) 
    {
        $otype = $_GET['type'];
    } 
    else 
    {
        $otype = 'm';
    }

    $statusFile = "d:\\CLIENTS\\status.txt";

    $file_handler = fopen($statusFile, "r"); 

    // read the contents 
    $contents = fread($file_handler, filesize($statusFile)); 

    // close the file 
    fclose($file_handler); 

    if (strcasecmp($otype, "m") == 0)
    {
        echo $contents;  
    } 
    else 
    {
        $lines = explode("\n",$contents);
        $frow = explode(",", $lines[0]);

        if (strcmp($frow[1],"1") == 0) 
        {
            echo "Update Status: <b>Complete</b>";
            //to count total lines in txt file
            $statusFile = "d:\\CLIENTS\\status.txt";
            $line = count(file($statusFile)); 
            echo "There are".$line."lines in"; 
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Update Status: <b>Incomplete</b>";
        }

        echo "<table border=\"1\">";
        for ($count = 1; $count < sizeof($lines); $count++) 
        {
            $fields = explode(",",$lines[$count]);
            $sz = sizeof($fields);
            if ($sz > 1) 
            {
                $str = "OK";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $fields[0] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $fields[1] . "</td>";
                //echo "<td>" . $fields[2] . "</td>";

                if (strpos($fields[2],'OK') !== false) 
                {
                    echo "<td><font color='green'>". $fields[2] ."</font></td>";

                    //echo "<td style='background-color: #00FF00;'>". $fields[2] ."</td>"; 
                } 
                else 
                {
                    //echo "<td><font color='red'>". $fields[2] ."</font></td>";
                    echo "<td style='background-color: #FF0000;'>". $fields[2] ."</td>"; 
                }


            echo "</tr>";

        }
    }
        echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: check $count<=50 then from 51 to 100

Comment: or... `if ($count % 50 == 0) { /* close table and start a new one */ }` to wrap each 50 records into table

Comment: can you edit code....

Comment: You should split your code into two parts - function that reads the file, and function that displays it. The read function should return an array of lines, and the display function can use array_chunk() to split it into two parts evenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a foreach instead of a for and $count to calculate if it is needed to echo a table tag. $count is only incremented when a row was inserted.

```
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%; /* Change the width to the desired width */
    padding: 0;
}
div.container table {
    width: 50%; /* Change the width to half of the width of the div */
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<?php
if(isset ($_GET['type'])) 
{
    $otype = $_GET['type'];
} 
else 
{
    $otype = 'm';
}

$statusFile = "d:\\CLIENTS\\status.txt";

$file_handler = fopen($statusFile, "r"); 

// read the contents 
$contents = fread($file_handler, filesize($statusFile)); 

// close the file 
fclose($file_handler); 

if (strcasecmp($otype, "m") == 0)
{
    echo $contents;  
} 
else 
{
    $lines = explode("\n",$contents);
    $frow = explode(",", $lines[0]);

    if (strcmp($frow[1],"1") == 0) 
    {
        echo "Update Status: <b>Complete</b>";
        //to count total lines in txt file
        $statusFile = "d:\\CLIENTS\\status.txt";
        $line = count(file($statusFile)); 
        echo "There are".$line."lines in"; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Update Status: <b>Incomplete</b>";
    }

    echo '<div class="conatiner">';
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($lines as $currLine) 
    {

        $fields = explode(",",$currLine);

        $sz = sizeof($fields);
        if ($sz > 1) 
        {
            if ($count == 0) {
                echo "<table border=\"1\">";
            }
            elseif ($count % 50 == 0) {
                echo "</table>";
                echo "<table border=\"1\">";

            }
            $str = "OK";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $fields[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $fields[1] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $fields[2] . "</td>";

            if (strpos($fields[2],'OK') !== false) 
            {
                 echo "<td><font color='green'>". $fields[2] ."</font></td>";

                 //echo "<td style='background-color: #00FF00;'>". $fields[2] ."</td>"; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                 //echo "<td><font color='red'>". $fields[2] ."</font></td>";
                 echo "<td style='background-color: #FF0000;'>". $fields[2] ."</td>"; 
             }


            echo "</tr>";
            $count++;

        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: It's just an example based on a part of your code. But if you replace the for loop with this foreach it should work. Can you tell me what you tried to implement it? What is going wrong?

Comment: I noticed that you skip the first line. Was that intended? I will edit that including a possible conflicting variable `$line`. I don't know what you mean exactly with irregular but does it have something to do with the first line?

Comment: actually i posted whole complete code. and my code fetching rows from text file....and displayed in tabular format on web..but it display like long list..so i want to split data(rows from text file) in 2 tables..
and in table there are 3 columns..so after 50 rows create new table side by side and display another remaning 50 rows

Comment: and it is easy if you post whole code...so there will be less confusion

Comment: I see what went wrong, a stupid mistake by me. The table close tag had to be above the opening tag. I posted the complete code

Comment: code works correct...but tables created in sequence..not side by side....
the separete tables created for every 50 records....

Comment: code works correct...but tables created in sequence..not side by side....
the separete tables created for every 50 records....
but i want it to display tables side by side...

Comment: That goes beyond your original question. But it can be done with css. You can use the `float: left` property for that. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917235/html-two-tables-horizontally-side-by-side).

Comment: Since it answered your posted question, could you mark this answer as correct please? For an answer on how to position the tables I would post a new question since that is something for the CSS experts out there.

Comment: actully i used your code....it gives 90% result correct..i.e. two table created for each 50 records....but the problem is 2nd table is not created to beside 1st table...it is created under 1st table...
so could you plz suggest any solution for above problem....so it will be perfect answer

Comment: I added an example of my suggestion to use float: left in a previous comment. Hope that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'float' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\trystatus.php on line 54
it throws an error

Comment: i used - echo "<table style="float: left;">";

Comment: plz do smthing wid it...i am already sick of this thing....mind stop working...smbdy plz helpppp

Comment: You are missing the \ in `echo "<table style=\"float: left;\">";`. If you use my example you can remove the `style=\"float: left;\"` part.

Comment: for example- add password to above code...if entered password is correct thn it display table

Comment: There are many options for that. You can use a web form and check with PHP or use `.htpasswd` if you have access to that. [See also this](http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html)

Comment: i am not using apache server..i am using wamp server...so plz u suggest some solution for put a password to above php page code...

Comment: WAMP stands for Windows, Apache, Mysql, PHP so it's definitely Apache. I suggest doing some research because that would save you a lot of time. This would be a good way to start: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115719/easy-way-to-password-protect-php-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115719/easy-way-to-password-protect-php-page)