# HTML / CSS Table Placement

Tags: html, css

Below is my code for 2x tables. There is PHP & results I have removed. But I cannot get these on one line but next to each other.

I have tried Align Left/Right and this puts them on 2x separate lines? I have tried float as well and this has not helped either.

Does anybody have advice for me?

**HTML**

```
<table width="40%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="table">
      <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="16" class="header"><center>Last 5 Received Transactions</center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td class="header"><center>Transaction ID</center></td>
        <td class="header"><center>Sent To</center></td>
        <td class="header"><center>Amount</center></td>
        <td class="header"><center>Date</center></td>
      </tr>
</table>
<table width="40%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="table">
      <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="16" class="header"><center>Last 5 Sent Transactions</center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td class="header"><center>Transaction ID</center></td>
        <td class="header"><center>Sent By</center></td>
        <td class="header"><center>Amount</center></td>
        <td class="header"><center>Date</center></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS :**

```
 table
    {
    border: #000000 1px solid;
    background-color: #363636;
    }
```

Comment: What is your CSS for?. I mean for which class is your CSS properties are that you mentioned above.

Comment: sorry I have edited now. the above CSS is for the class table

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML — Two Tables Horizontally Side by Side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917235/html-two-tables-horizontally-side-by-side)

Comment: I'm sorry, but why the `class="table"` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also add a class of left and right to each table and define floats in your css if you want the tables to always align left and right.

```
table.left {
  float: left;
}
table.right {
  float: right;
}

<table width="40%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="left">
  YOUR LEFT TABLE content
</table>
<table width="40%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="right">
  YOUR RIGHT TABLE content
</table>
```

You don't need the 'table' class because you can use the table tag as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **display:inline-block;**

**Update CSS**

```
table
{
border: #000000 1px solid;
background-color: #363636;
display:inline-block;
}
```

[WORKING:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kteof5LL/)

Comment: @Zoltan Does this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Float doesn't work on `display: table` which is the default table display property.

You have to put `display: block` on it in order to float them

```
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
table:first-child {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ma48ak4p/)