# side by side table is not working properly

Tags: html, css, html-table

I found the following css on the net and used it on my site to show a side by side tables. Most of them are working nicely in all three browsers, IE11, Chrome and Firefox except on one of my template. Although the tables show side by side but the content of the right table does not fully fill the cell correctly. Instead, it seems like the css creates two columns on the right table and only fill in the content of the left column leaving the right column blank. The right table only have one cell.

Here is the codes creating side by side tables:

```css
.zui-table {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 12px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.zui-table thead th {
  background-color: ##DDEFEF;
  ;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  ;
  color: #336B6B;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  ;
  color: #333;
  padding: 3px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table-horizontal tbody td {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <table CLASS="zui-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="medGreyText">Requester</div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="requester" class="inputReqText" value="somevalue" Required="True"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="medGreyText">Requesting Institution</div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <select Name="req_institution" id="req_institution" class="RegSelect" Required="True">
            <option value="">--- Please select Institution ---</option>
            <option value="xx">xx</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bb</option>
            <option value="cc">cc</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="medGreyText">Requester's Email</div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top"><input name="req_email" id="req_email" type="text" class="inputReqText" value="" Required="True"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="medGreyText">Entity Type</div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <select Name="type" class="RegSelect" Required="True">
            <option value="">---Please select entity type ---</option>
            <option value="Ind">Individual</option>
            <option value="Org">Organization</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="medGreyText">Advance ID</div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="idno" id="idno" class="inputReqText" value="" Required="True"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
          <br><br>
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="G E T  D A T A" class="SubmitButtons">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table CLASS="zui-table">
    &larr; the problem area!!! <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <b>OFFICE  POLICY</b><br> It is the goal of the XX research office to offer its' constituents quality.....forth and clarifying our procedures and explaining some of our methods etc....
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

As you see from the screenshot, the tables appear side by side but the content of the right table, the office policy, is not populating the whole cell but instead this css on this template creates two columns side by side. I've been debugging this since this morning with no success.

the css zui-table-horizontal tbody td does not seem to work???

[image]

Comment: Can you post the rest of the css? When I copy/paste your code it doesn't turn out like your example.

Comment: That's the only css. I added <div id="wrap"> to wrap the two tables. I found the css here: https://zinoui.com/blog/css-tables-tutorial I took the horizontal css from this blog and create the side by site tables using <div id="wrap"> is this not allowed?

Comment: What happens when you add `width: 50%; ` to `.zui-table`?

Comment: Sometimes this behaviour occurs with malformed HTML, and an extra or missing <td> tag.    You only include a snippet of your HTML in this post.  Did you pass the entire HTML page through a HTML formatter to check it?

Comment: I copied and pasted the codes from my template to this forum. if there is a malform html or extra or missing <td> I did not find those. I'll look into the suggestion, thank you

Comment: I get that you pasted your snippets here, but I was referring to the fully rendered HTML page output from your web browser, by using the browser "View Source" functionality.  It can be tricky to predict how to help if we can't see everything your browser is parsing.  When I view only your snippets in my browser it looks much different that your screenshot, so I can only assume that your browser is getting more than you have given us.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish 2 side-by-side tables with HTML/CSS.  There is already an SO answer here:

[HTML — Two Tables Horizontally Side by Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917235/html-two-tables-horizontally-side-by-side)

Their example of using one of these styles will solve most cases:

```
display: inline-block
```

or

```
float: left
```

There are a few things to consider though.  In responsive HTML on a mobile device, the tables as you have it will probably go one above the other, which is a good thing for the user experience.  If you force them to be side-by-side, the user many never see the right side table.

If side-by-side tables is what you really want, you could go old school and embed your tables in another table, and put each table in separate table columns.

For example, the following snippet generates what you want:

```css
.zui-table {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 12px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.zui-table thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 3px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table-horizontal tbody td {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table CLASS="zui-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <div class="medGreyText">Requester</div>
              </td>
              <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="requester" class="inputReqText" value="somevalue" Required="True"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <div class="medGreyText">Requesting Institution</div>
              </td>
              <td valign="top">
                <select Name="req_institution" id="req_institution" class="RegSelect" Required="True">
                  <option value="">--- Please select Institution ---</option>
                  <option value="xx">xx</option>
                  <option value="aa">aa</option>
                  <option value="bb">bb</option>
                  <option value="cc">cc</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <div class="medGreyText">Requester's Email</div>
              </td>
              <td valign="top"><input name="req_email" id="req_email" type="text" class="inputReqText" value="" Required="True"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <div class="medGreyText">Entity Type</div>
              </td>
              <td valign="top">
                <select Name="type" class="RegSelect" Required="True">
                  <option value="">---Please select entity type ---</option>
                  <option value="Ind">Individual</option>
                  <option value="Org">Organization</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <div class="medGreyText">Advance ID</div>
              </td>
              <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="idno" id="idno" class="inputReqText" value="" Required="True"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" colspan="2">
                <br><br>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="G E T  D A T A" class="SubmitButtons">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table CLASS="zui-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <b>OFFICE  POLICY</b><br> It is the goal of the XX research office to offer its' constituents quality.....forth and clarifying our procedures and explaining some of our methods etc....
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is another solution, yes I just need to put this two table side by side since the user interface is so small, thank you!!!

Comment: @ArtOfCode - thanks for the snippet.  I need to learn that trick.

Comment: @ByteSlinger Button in the editor toolbar, next to the insert image button. Or just Ctrl-M.