# Use sp_send_dbmail to have two horizontally aligned tables

Tags: html, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I've referred to this question: [HTML — Two Tables Horizontally Side by Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917235/html-two-tables-horizontally-side-by-side)

In SQL I have tried the following:

1.

```
DECLARE @HTML NVARCHAR(2000);
SET @HTML = 
N'
    <table border=1 style=''display: inline-block''>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border=1 style=''display: inline-block''>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
'

EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = 'me@blahblah.co.uk',
    @subject = 'foo',
    @body_format = 'html',
    @body = @HTML
```

2.

```
DECLARE @HTML NVARCHAR(2000);
SET @HTML = 
N'
    <table border=1 style=''float: left''>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border=1 style=''float: left''>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
'

EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = 'me@blahblah.co.uk',
    @subject = 'foo',
    @body_format = 'html',
    @body = @HTML
```

Neither 1 or 2 aligns the tables side-by-side in the email. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are missing the `HTML` tag try the below one.

Add second table `float` property to `right` and both table `display` property to `inline-table`.

```
DECLARE @HTML NVARCHAR(2000);
SET @HTML = N'<html> <body>  <table border=1 style=''float: left; display: inline-table;''>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border=1 style=''float: right; display: inline-table;''>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </body>
</html>'
```

Comment: Did you test your proposal? I already tried with these tags included

Comment: I have tested in the browser and it is showing two tables horizontally.

Comment: Thanks. I know it works in the browser but my question is not about the browser

Comment: no this doesn't work - to be honest you've simply repeated what I've already detailed in the question. Are you using SQL-server to test your suggestions?